# Configuration successful but never gets imported

Tags: 8, configuration, entities

I have some changes in core.entity_form_display.node.news.default.  When I run drush cim -y it says it is successful but it actually never imports it.

```
drush cim -y                         
Collection  Config                                      Operation                
             core.entity_form_display.node.news.default  update
Import the listed configuration changes? (y/n): y
The configuration was imported successfully.            [success]
```

The changes are removing field groups from the form display.

If I try to import via UI it also says it is successful but it never gets imported.  I don't get any errors in my error log.

[image]

I tried to make some other configuration changes like changing the site name and it works. It seems to be an issue with Field Group or at least when deleting a field from from a form display.

Comment: Sounds like https://www.drupal.org/node/2666392?

Comment: @Berdir Applying that patch ended up fixing the issue for me. Do you mind posting that as answer so I can give you credit.  Thanks again (I think you saved me like a couple times already).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a known core bug: https://drupal.org/node/2666392

Comment: makes me so sad that still happens